# Adding interactive elements in html web page to pickup color

Tags: html

I'm not a web developer, I'm an electronic developer and trying to develop a simple webpage to pickup color with 3 sliders, a sample box and a button.

The whole idea is to move the sliders until you get the color you need; that color is visible in a sample box which is a rectangle next to the "send button" and this box change with the color selected by the sliders.

I manage to create the custom sliders but now I need the button that sends the 3 slider values and the "onSliderChange" action that update the sample box color.

This page will be inserted in an ESP8266 Arduino project to control an RGB LED.

Here's my code until now.

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.rSlider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 50%;
  height: 15px;
  background: #FF0000;
  outline: 1;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.rSlider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.rSlider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #04AA6D;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rSlider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #04AA6D;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gSlider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 50%;
  height: 15px;
  background: #00FF00;
  outline: 1;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.gSlider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.gSlider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #04AA6D;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gSlider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #04AA6D;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bSlider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 50%;
  height: 15px;
  background: #0000FF;
  outline: 1;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.bSlider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.bSlider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #04AA6D;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bSlider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #04AA6D;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h1>Custom Range Slider</h1>

<div class="slidecontainer">

  <p>Custom range slider:</p>
  <a>R</a><input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="50" class="rSlider" id="rRange">
  <br><br>
  <a>G</a><input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="50" class="gSlider" id="gRange">
  <br><br>
  <a>B</a><input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="50" class="bSlider" id="bRange">
  <br><br>

</div>
```

Comment: ....or you could just eliminate **all** of that and use just a single `<input type="color">`.

Comment: I tried in my PC and work nice. Do that work on phones too?

Comment: Yes: https://caniuse.com/input-color (Opera Mini doesn't count as those pages aren't really interactive, it's meant for ultra-low-end Java phones - I don't personally know anyone with one, I haven't even seen one in over 10 years).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

....or you could just eliminate all of that and use just a single `<input type="color">`:

It's very widely supported https://caniuse.com/input-color - except for Opera Mini and KaiOS' Browser, both of which target ultra-low-end phones - I don't personally know anyone with a phone running Opera Mini nor KaiOS; I haven't even seen anyone running Java (excepting Android) on a phone in over 12 years.

```css
#slidecontainer {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Custom Range Slider</h1>

<div id="slidecontainer">

    <label>
        Click me
        <br />
        <input
            type="color"
            value="#123456"
            id="colorInput" 
            oninput="this.closest('div').style.backgroundColor = this.value;"
        />

    </label>
</div>
```